# Can't print path field in view twig

Tags: views

I have custom twig for a view (views-view--new-blogs--page-1.html.twig) where i can't print the path field for read more link. 
How to print the path field in the above twig.

Comment: How are you trying to print it? You don't have to print your own read more button. Views gives you the option to add link to content.

Answer (score 0):

Enable debugging by these commands:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates

When debugging is enabled and you go to the subpage with this view, you will see a full link in the comments.